# Fixing conversation_id from being NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

I replaced my custom inbox messaging system with the mailboxer gem. I have a issue with the Q&A feature on the app. The Question is not being sent to the users inbox so it can be answered. The question shows in the `notifications` table, however the `conversation_id` is NULL. With no `conversation_id` being generated the Question will never be delivered to the recipients inbox.

Can someone take a look at my code and see what went wrong?

Questions Controller:

```
  def index
    @questions = Question.all
    respond_with(@questions)
end

def show
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  @questions = Question.order("created_at DESC")
  respond_with(@questions)
end

def new
  @question = Question.new
  respond_with(@question)
end

def create
  @question = Question.new(params[:question])
  if @question.save
    #Original code @message = Message.create
    @message = current_user.messages.new(:subject => "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}",
                           #Original code :sender_id
                           :notification_id => @question.sender_id,
                           #Original code :recipient_id
                           :receiver_id => @question.recipient_id,
                           :body => @question.question)

    @question.message = @message
    @question.save
    redirect_to questions_path, notice: 'Your question was saved successfully. Thanks!'
  else
    render :new, alert: 'Sorry. There was a problem saving your question.'
  end
end

  def update
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @question.update_attributes(:answer => params[:question][:answer])
    redirect_to user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox => "inbox")
end
end
```

Messages Controller:

```
 def index
      redirect_to conversations_path(:box => @box)
    end

  # GET /message/new
  def new
    @message = current_user.messages.new
  end

   # POST /message/create
  def create
    @recipient = User.find(params[:user])
    current_user.send_message(@recipient, params[:body], params[:subject])
    flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent!"
    redirect_to :conversations
  end
  end
```

Message form:

```
 <%= @user %>
 <%= form_tag({controller: "messages", action: "create"}, method: :post) do %>
  <%= label_tag :subject %>
  <%= text_field_tag :subject %>
  <%= label :body, "Message text" %>
  <%= text_area_tag :body %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:user, "#{:user_id}") %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Send message', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 <% end %>
```

Questions form:

```
<h1>New Question</h1>
<%= form_for @question do |f| %>
<%= @question.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
<li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
    <ul>
        <li><%= f.text_field :question, {:placeholder => 'Please add your question...'} %></li>
    <%= f.hidden_field :sender_id, :value => current_user.id %>
        <li><%= f.hidden_field :recipient_id, :value => params[:user_id] %></li>
        <li><%= f.submit %></li>
        </ul>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to "Back", questions_path, :class => "button" %>
```

Comment: If you look in your log file you should see exactly what is being passed through to the controller in params.  You can then step through the controller code and see where the problem occurs.  It might be obvious as soon as you see params.  If there is a problem with what is in params, then the form that's submitting to the controller is at fault.

Comment: Btw you get the stringify_keys method when you pass a string, instead of a hash, to update_attributes.  So it sounds like params[:question] is a string, rather than a hash.

Comment: In your Questions controller Create action try changing `@question = Question.new(params[:question])` to `@question = Question.create(params[:question])`. New only creates the local object but does not attempt to validate or save it to the database. You already created the local object in your New action.

Comment: I think you should change the workflow a little. Try changing what I  mentioned above so that you can create the Question and save it to the database. Once the Question is saved, I think your Questions Controller should be able to take that saved object and attach it to your body parameter when you create the message.

Comment: @james The question was being saved to the database with the original create action `@question = Question.new(params[:question])`. The issue was no conversation_id is being created. Without a conversation_id the Question will never be sent to the Users inbox. I believe the problem is stemming from the form itself, not the controller.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I don't have access to my development machine right now but I'll look at this tonight. In the meantime let's discuss some possible solutions. 1. Can you use `current_user.send_message(@recipient, params[:body], params[:subject])` instead of message.new in your Questions controller? That method should fill in a valid value for conversation_I'd. I think I ran into the same issue when I tried using message.new.

Comment: @james With the current code it creates a Question and a message_id is assigned to it. When the User reads the question it's not to start a conversation, because there will be no direct conversation. Inside the message will be the form view to answer the question. and once answered it will post to that Users profile. Since the Question is being created and assigned a id inside the Notifications table there should be a way to display all messages in Inbox if conversation_id is NULL or NOT NULL. You think that would work?

Comment: @CorneliusWilson If you don't need the Conversations component then this will work if your application is populating the receipts table with the recipient data in addition to the notifications table.

Comment: @CorneliusWilson did you ever get this working OK?

Comment: @james I need the Conversations component for the regular 2-way messaging between users so unfortunately I can't get rid of it. I think for questions to be assigned a conversation_id I am going have to move it all to the Messages controller. Then add it to the routes, `resources :messages do post :new collection do get :question`. Add a view under the /messages. I will give that a shot and see how it works. If that doesn't work then I'm out of ideas of how to get Questions to create a conversation_id. It's creating a message_id, recipient, and sender id but not conversation.

Comment: Did you try using the send_message method? I think that should create the conversion id for you. Message.new won't create conversations. Check out the definition of the method in the mailboxer wiki:   http://rubydoc.info/github/ging/mailboxer/Mailboxer/Models/Messageable/InstanceMethods:send_message

Comment: The send message method give a `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch` with the error message `Message(#2187869200) expected, got Receipt(#2188572300)`. It points to this line `@question.message = @message`

Comment: The only thing I can keep going back to is the view. The controller seems to be setup fine. When submitting a question it posts to the Question & Messages table. A message_id is even created that is shown properly in the Questions table. Only the conversation_id is not created inside the Notifications table. Perhaps in the view I need to reference the Messages controller create action.

Comment: @james I had to finish some other sections of the app. I went back to mailboxer and tried the send_message method with `@message = current_user.send_message(@question.recipient_id, @question.question, "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}")`. The error sends me a NoMethodError `undefined method `primary_key' for Fixnum:Class` The error prevents from connecting to the Notifications table and it doesn't create a message_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like you set conversation_id anywhere? Try passing it as part of the options hash to current_user.messages.new(…)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
<li><%= text_field_tag :question, {:placeholder => 'Please add your question...'} %></li>
```

this will set params[:question] to be a string.  Your controller action is expecting it to be a hash.  Maybe it should be

```
text_field_tag "question[text]" ...
```

or whatever the field that holds the text of the question is.

Comment: Produces the same error with the removal of placeholder. I switched the view to using form_for instead and I can have the question submit to the database inside the Conversations table with no errors. The only problem is doesn't produce a conversation_id (stays NULL) which means the Question will never be sent to the recipients inbox. I added the new view to the bottom of original post.